# When does the Punisher surrender to the Avengers in a theme park?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, the-punisher

I remember reading an extract of a recent Punisher comic, and need help identifying the exact issue/series it came from.

I read it a few years ago, so between 2013 and 2015. The style is similar to, but not exactly the same as, that of "Welcome Back Frank".

While I only read the very end of it, it was implied the issue started with the Punisher somehow fighting with Spider-Man, who asked the Avenger's help to put him down.

The part I read took place in a empty theme park, where the Punisher single-handedly held off Spider-Man, Black Widow, Iron Man and Thor, before surrendering and being put in a specially designed prison in the Antarctic Ocean, designed by Tony Stark.

I also remember a reference to a girl, allied with the Punisher, who takes his role after that.

What I am searching for is the number of this issue, and if possible, a identification of that "Punisher girl" to know if she got a standalone series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the Punisher, but looking around it's probably either

**Punisher War Zone v3, #4 (30 January 2013)**

or

**Punisher War Zone v3, #5 (27 February 2013)**

Which one, or possibly both, depends a bit more exactly on what you read and where the elements you remember first appeared, which, not having read the issues myself, I can't analyze, but I believe #5 is your best bet.

The woman would then be [Rachel Cole-Aves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Cole-Alves).  I actually found her first by looking up Punisher allies, but then in her Wikipedia biography there's this description:

> The Punisher, despite being hunted by the Avengers, frees Rachel
>   (which she initially protests) with the help of Wolverine. Knowing his
>   capture by the Avengers is inevitable, the Punisher gives Rachel
>   everything she needs to relocate, and reassures her by saying, "The
>   mission isn't the man, sergeant. It never was". Rachel is next shown
>   gunning down a pair of muggers in Hollywood.[21][22]

The cite links suggest War Zone #4 as the issue where the torch is passed happens, and #5 as where she's next shown.  [This review of issue #5](http://www.craveonline.com/site/449049-review-punisher-war-zone-5) also contains an amusement park:

> Castle is held up in an amusement park, which I dig because it brings
>   in shades of the old Parker novels by Richard Stark, but I digress.
>   He’s leading them there not to fight them, but to give Cole-Alves time
>   to escape.

and an undersea prison:

> Punisher: War Zone #5 ends with Castle being held in a special
>   containment center at the bottom of Lake Michigan.

If the woman you're thinking of is Rachel Cole-Aves, she did not appear to have her own series, just the very rare cameo (including one in a video game) since.

Comment: It s a shame for Rachel, it would have been a good idea for marvel to at least try to give her the "main" Punisher role and see where it goes. Thanks a lot.